# OpenMPI hanging with "No protocol specified"

Tags: ubuntu, x11, openmpi

I'm trying a simple OpenMPI job and it hangs inexplicibly with error `No protocol specified`.

Specifically, I have a simple program below:

```
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    //MPI_Finalize(); // Commented to isolate MPI_Init() problem.
    return 1;
}
```

which I compile with mpicc on Ubuntu 20.04.1. When I run this either by itself (`a.out`) or with mpirun, I get the hang and `no protocol specified`. I also get this when I just run `mpirun` by itself (mpirun v4.0.3).

I've seen this is an [issue](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/7701) with openmpi where it is seemingly associated with X11 for some reason but have not seen any resolution. Does anyone know a workaround to this issue? Happy to post more details as needed.

Comment: Hi mate, I trust you have seen this tread ? https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/7701 it does look like an ongoing investigation ^^